# Awk multiple columns in 2 files and output the matching lines

Tags: awk

I have a 2 input files, as follows
x.txt

```
C20775336       maker   gene    1895    2166    .       -       .       ID=gene1;Name=maker-C20775336-augustus-gene-0.0
C20775336       maker   gene    3097    4624    .       -       .       Parent=mRNA1
```

file 2 y.txt

```
scaffold4557    hsal_OGSv3.3    gene    3097    4624    74.8    +       .       ID=HSAL10661-RA;Parent=HSAL10661;Name=HSAL10661-RA;Alias=Hsal_17580--XP_001599845.1_NASVI
C20775336       maker   gene     1895    1962    .       -       2       ID=CDS1;Parent=mRNA1
```

I would like to compare column 4 in both the files and column 5 in both the files, if it satisfies both the conditions , then print that line from file 2
In the above case..output should be as follows:

```
scaffold4557    hsal_OGSv3.3    gene    3097    4624    74.8    +       .       ID=HSAL10661-RA;Parent=HSAL10661;Name=HSAL10661-RA;Alias=Hsal_17580--XP_001599845.1_NASVI
```

I tried using awk, but was not successful. thanks in advance

Comment: "If it satisfies both the conditions"...  WHAT conditions exactly?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{seen[$4,$5]=1;next} ($4,$5) in seen' x.txt y.txt 
scaffold4557    hsal_OGSv3.3    gene    3097    4624    74.8    +       .       ID=HSAL10661-RA;Parent=HSAL10661;Name=HSAL10661-RA;Alias=Hsal_17580--XP_001599845.1_NASVI
```

Comment: I was looking for a similar answer except my 5 th column in file1 is a subset of 5 th column in file 2, in that case how can I compare both?

Comment: @AishwaryaKulkarni Can you be precise about what "subset" means?  (Maybe open a new question with the details.)

Comment: Hi @John1024 I created a new question   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882681/finding-rows-from-file2-in-file1-which-have-extended-columns-in-file2, Thanks