# finding rows from file2 in file1 which have extended columns in file2

Tags: awk, split, file-comparison

I have file1 as:

```
ABC CDEF HAGD CBDGCBAHS:ATSVHC
NBS JHA AUW MNDBE:BWJW
DKW QDW OIW KNDSK:WLKJW
BNSHW JBSS IJS BSHJA
ABC CDEF CBS 234:ATSVHC
DKW QDW FSD 634:WLKJW
```

and file2:

```
ABC CDEF HAGD CBDGCBAHS:ATSVHC:THE:123
NBS JHA AUW MNDBE:BWJW:THE:243
DKW QDW OIW KNDSK:WLKJW:THE:253
KAB GCBS YSTW SHSEB:AGTW:THE:193
```

I want to compare file 1 and file 2 based on column 1,2,3 and 4 except that column 4 in file2 has a bit of an extension to compare with, by using

```
awk 'FNR==NR{seen[$1,$2,$3,$4;next} ($1,$2,$3,$4) in seen' file1 file2
```

what can I tweak to make it comparable such that my output are the matched lines in file2 as:

```
ABC CDEF HAGD CBDGCBAHS:ATSVHC:THE:123
NBS JHA AUW MNDBE:BWJW:THE:243
DKW QDW OIW KNDSK:WLKJW:THE:253
```

Comment: edit your Q to show your expected output, given these inputs. AND why are you referencing `$5` in your code? Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include `:` in the FS:

```
$ awk -F'[ :]' 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5];next} ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5) in a' file1 file2
ABC CDEF HAGD CBDGCBAHS:ATSVHC:THE:123
NBS JHA AUW MNDBE:BWJW:THE:243
DKW QDW OIW KNDSK:WLKJW:THE:253
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you want to print lines from file2 that have fields 1, 2, 3, matching the corresponding fields in file1 and also have the beginning part of field 4 in file2 matching field 4 in file1.  In that case:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{seen[$1,$2,$3,$4];next} {a=$4; sub(/:[^:]*:[^:]*$/, "", a)} ($1,$2,$3,a) in seen' file1 file2
ABC CDEF HAGD CBDGCBAHS:ATSVHC:THE:123
NBS JHA AUW MNDBE:BWJW:THE:243
DKW QDW OIW KNDSK:WLKJW:THE:253
```

#### How it works

- `FNR==NR{seen[$1,$2,$3,$4];next}`

  While reading the first file, file1, we add ato associative array `seen` a key which is equal to the first four fields.  We then skip the rest of the commands and jump to the `next` line.
- `a=$4; sub(/:[^:]*:[^:]*$/, "", a)`

  If we get to here, that means we are working on file2.

  This assigns the value of field 4 to variable `a` and then removes the last two colon-separated strings from `a`.
- `($1,$2,$3,a) in seen`

  This prints any line in file2 for which the first three fields and `a` are a key in associative array `seen`.